# onclick event is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am having a hard time figuring out how to use a click event on IE11. My code works with chrome, firefox but does not work in Internet Explorer 11. Here is my code:

```
$(".burger-menu").on("click",function(){
    $(".fullscreen-nav-container").fadeToggle(700);
});
```

HTML used:

```
<input id="burger" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="burger" class="burger-menu">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
```

What to do?

Comment: What exactly is not working ? is it the click or fadeToggle ?

Comment: Can you post some HTML?

Comment: @Ashvin777 the click event.

Comment: Are you sure that when you are doing this binding, this element is present and rendered in the DOM properly ? May try to add this under DOMContentLoaded event and check

Comment: @JacopoLanzoni  sure, attaching it.

Comment: @Ashvin777 - Then it wouldn't work in Chrome or Firefox either.

Answer (score 1):

In all browsers, you're hooking click on the wrong element. You should use `#burger`, not `.burger-menu`, because clicking the `label` triggers `click` on the `input type="checkbox"`:

```js
$("#burger").on("click",function(){
    $(".fullscreen-nav-container").fadeToggle(700);
});
```

```html
<input id="burger" type="checkbox" />
<label for="burger" class="burger-menu">
    <span>x</span>
    <span>x</span>
    <span>x</span>
</label>
<div class="fullscreen-nav-container">
Container
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11. (Whereas it doesn't work in any of them when hooking `click` on the `label`.)